# prototype cell ==nil xcode6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I create my `UITableView`, the tableview does not come with an prototype cell so I delete the original view and added an `UITableView`. However, when the new tableview was created, the prototype still not appear, so I drag an tablecell in to the table view and named the identifier "Cell" in storyboard. However, when I tried to populate my parse query in to the tableview cell, it keep crashing, so i put an cell==nil and found out the cell is equals to nil. I wonder what have i done wrong? or if theres anyway to identify the cell?

my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    PFObject *shop=[self.shops objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [shop objectForKey:@"Shopname"];
    return cell;
}
```

my cell
[image]

update:
[image]

[image]

Comment: In the identifier field should be cell or cell1.  Identifier field has to match with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cell identifier in your original code sample was "Cell1" whereas the cell identifier in the storyboard simply "Cell". These must be the same identifier.

BTW, if you have cell prototype, you should not insert that `if (cell == nil) { ... }` clause in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The `cell` should not be `nil`, so you should diagnose that problem rather than manually instantiating the table view cell. Also, you specified table cell type of "Custom" but appear to handling it like it was "Basic". I wouldn't use "Custom" cell type unless you were really using custom subclass for the cell.

If your app is still crashing, the question is whether the error message the same. Please update your original question with the full text of any error messages you may receive (specifically what shows up in the console). If you have a stack trace, share that with us, too.

Also please refer to [So my app crashed, now what?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) for general counsel when you have errors.

Comment: Hi, Im sorry, but i actually changed it to "Cell", but my list still not appear, any help?